# Where clause between dates with pivot table without losing data

Tags: sql, date, pivot-table, where-clause, temp-tables

I'm trying to display some data based on work done by users across some tables

**Tasks**

```
TaskID       TaskTitle
----------------------
1            Job 1
2            Job 2
3            Job 3
```

**Work Table**

```
JobID        AssignedTo
----------------------------
1            guid1
2            guid2
3            guid3
```

Users Table

```
UsersGuid    UserName
------------------
guid1        Username1
guid2        Username2
guid3        Username3
```

And what I want to display is something like the following

```
Task   UserName1     UserName2     UserName3
Task1  0             0             0
Task2  0             97            4
Task3  0             6             0
Task4  2             40            55
```

I have the following code but the problem I am having is I want it to still show the task name even if there has never been anything worked on it, but if there's no values found it doesn't display it.

```
create table #TempTable
        (
            JobID int,
            TaskID int, 
            TaskTitle varchar(max),
            UserName varchar(max)
        )

INSERT INTO #TempTable

    select
    Job.JobID,
    Job.TaskID,
    tasks.TaskTitle,
    users.UserName as AssignedName

    from TaskLookups tasks

    left join Jobs job on
    tasks.TaskID = job.TaskID

    left join Users users on
    job.TaskAssignedTo = users.UserID

    WHERE
    (job.JobDateTime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-07-01 23:59:00', 102))

declare @query as nvarchar(max),
@cols as nvarchar(max)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(UserName) 
                    from StaffUsers
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 
    '
    Select * From #TempTable 
    pivot ( count(JobID) For UserName in(' + @cols + ')) as Result order by TaskTitle
    '
exec sp_executesql @query
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although you left join to `Jobs`, you then use `job.JobDateTime` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
(job.JobDateTime BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-07-01 23:59:00', 102))
```

Any task without a job in the given datetime would have a value of `NULL` for `job.JobDateTime`, and `NULL` is not between 1st December 2016 and 1st July 2017, so the entire row is removed, thus removing the task. Effectively making your left join an inner join.

You should move the predicate to the join condition:

```
LEFT JOIN Jobs job 
    ON tasks.TaskID = job.TaskID 
    AND job.JobDateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-12-01', 102) 
    AND job.JobDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-07-02', 102)
```

N.B I have changed `BETWEEN` to an open ended range, for reasons set out in this article: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: That's great and done the trick, thank you! Didn't think I could have been to far off!

Answer (score 0):

Add `UNION ALL` and SELECT the unassigned tasks list( WHERE JobId is NULL) and put usernames as 0 for them.